# setting properties for Gradle subproject

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I have a multi-project Gradle build. In each subproject I have a `properties.gradle` file like the following:

```
def usefulMethod() {
    return 'foo'
}

ext {
    foo = 'bar'
    usefulMethod = this.&usefulMethod
}
```

And then I import it into the subproject `build.gradle` using `apply from: './properties.gradle'`.

However, if two subprojects import a variable with the same name, I get this error:

```
Cannot add extension with name 'foo', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

It seems that adding to `ext` affects the entire project instead of just the subproject like I wanted. What is the correct way to import properties and variables from an external file in a subproject without leaking them into the entire project build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plain `ext` is the extension for ENTIRE project, the root project and all subprojects. To avoid polluting the root namespace whenever you include a file via `apply from...`, you should instead use `project.ext`. `project` refers to the current project or subproject being built. For example, the below file could be `apply from`'d to add a `downloadFile` function to the current project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.4.3'
    }
}

project.ext {
    apply plugin: de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.DownloadTaskPlugin

    downloadFile = { String url, File destination ->
        if (destination.exists()) {
            println "Skipping download because ${destination} already exists"
        } else {
            download {
                src url
                dest destination
            }
        }
    }
}
```